# How to connect to Sybase ASA server remotely using ado .net

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, sqlanywhere, sybase-asa

I have an application using a Sybase ASA 6.0 database.

1. How can I connect directly to Sybase from Visual Studio 2010 to collect my data? How do I get the data provider?
2. How can I move the database to an MS-SQL server? Can I import the database directly to SQL Server from ASA?

I have downloaded SQL Anywhere Developer Edition v12  just in case I need it.